# Inserindo arestas em um grafo via lista de adjacência

Tags: c, grafo, inserir

Olá. Estou tentando programar meu primeiro grafo, via lista de adjacência.

O resultado não está saindo como esperado, uma vez que não consigo obter o retorno da função inserir_aresta.

O código simples é o seguinte:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct grafo{
    int pond;// é ponderado?
    int n; // número de vértices
    int grau_max; // grau máximo (para implementar em vetor)
    int** arestas; //matriz de arestas
    float** pesos; //matriz de pesos para as arestas
    int* grau; //vetor de grau para os vértices
}GRAFO;

GRAFO* cria_grafo(int n, int grau_max, int pond){
    GRAFO* gr=(GRAFO*) malloc(sizeof(GRAFO));
    if(gr!=NULL){
        gr->pond=pond;
        gr->n=n;
        gr->grau_max=grau_max;
        gr->grau=(int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int)); //calloc inicializa o espaço de memória usando zeros
        gr->arestas=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        gr->pesos=(float**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            gr->arestas[i]=(int*)malloc(grau_max*sizeof(int));
            gr->pesos[i]=(float*)malloc(grau_max*sizeof(float));
        }
    }
    printf("Grafo com %d vertices\n", n);
    return gr;
}

void inserir_aresta(GRAFO* gr, int ini, int fim, int orient, float peso){
    if(gr==NULL) printf("Falhou");
    else{
        if(ini<0 || ini>=gr->n) printf("Falhou");
        else{if(fim<0 || fim>=gr->n) printf("Falhou");
        else{
        gr->arestas[ini][gr->grau[ini]]=fim;
        if(orient==0) inserir_aresta(gr, fim, ini, orient, peso);
        if (gr->pond!=0) gr->pesos[ini][gr->grau[ini]]=peso;
        gr->grau[ini]++;
        printf("Sucesso");}
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    GRAFO* gr=cria_grafo(5, 4, 0);
    inserir_aresta(gr, 0, 1, 0, 1);

}
```

Coloquei os "printf's" para tentar acompanhar a criação do grafo mesmo antes de chamar uma função de impressão. Parece que a função cria_grafo está funcionando de acordo, pois consigo a resposta

**Grafo com 5 vertices.**

Porém, as respostas "Falhou" ou "Sucesso" da função de inserção não aparecem. Poderiam me ajudar?

Muito obrigada desde já pela atenção.

Answer (score -2):

Problema solucionado: A recursão estava sendo colocada no lugar errado. A função funciona da seguinte forma:

```
void inserir_aresta(GRAFO* gr, int ini, int fim, int orient, float peso){
    if(gr==NULL) printf("Falhou\n");
    else{
        if(ini<0 || ini>=gr->n) printf("Falhou\n");
        else{if(fim<0 || fim>=gr->n) printf("Falhou\n");
        else{
        if(gr->arestas[ini][gr->grau[ini]]==NULL) gr->arestas[ini][gr->grau[ini]]=fim;
        if (gr->pond!=0) gr->pesos[ini][gr->grau[ini]]=peso;
        gr->grau[ini]++;
        printf("Sucesso\n");
        if(orient==0) inserir_aresta(gr, fim, ini, 3, peso);} //3 para impedir loop infinito
        }
    }
}
```